# DB engine for "cache" purposes

Tags: database, caching, postgresql-9.1

my relational databases are quite big, up to 250-300GB in size, tables containing 200m rows etc. I use postgresql as engine. I think I do not need relational database for all purposes, but changing it now would need months of developments.

For many purposes I need just most recent data, like last week or so. My current solution simply use caching - I created several tables which are being truncated and populated every 1-5-60 minutes.

The problem with Postgres is that it's not best solution. Each delete create dead tuples and tables have to be vacuumed. I was wondering if I could engage any nosql database for such purpose? Perhaps you could advise me on a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tarantool http://tarantool.org should be the best solution here as it is a real in memory DB with speed of memcached, even faster but with persistence, so you won't have a cache warming problem. The same is true about data compaction problem - in Tarantool it is done in background without additional memory or CPU consumption.